# trying to use if in tensorflow's map_fn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to apply a transformation to a column vector using map_fn in tensorflow, and it's not working.

For the following column vector:

```
elems = np.array([[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]])
```

When I do this:

```
tf_m = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x + 1.0, elems)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(tf_m)
    print(str(res))
```

I get the result that I expect, namely this column vector:

```
[[2.]
 [3.]
 [4.]]
```

However, when I do this:

```
tf_m2 = tf.map_fn(lambda x: x+1 if x % 2 > 0 else x, elems)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    res = sess.run(tf_m2)
    print(str(res))
```

The code fails with the following exception:

> TypeError: Using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed. Use `if t is not None:` instead of `if t:` to test if a tensor is defined, and use TensorFlow ops such as tf.cond to execute subgraphs conditioned on the value of a tensor.

I've tried printing the type of x, and it's a tensor with shape (1,).  So, what it looks like is happening is that the values aren't being passed into the lambda as scalar values, but rather as tensors with shape (1,); the % is broadcast, producing another tensor of shape (1,), but that tensor can't then have the >= operator applied to it.

Is there a way to make this work?  Is there a way to get an *actual* scalar that I could apply the >= operator to?  If there isn't, is there an efficient alternative to map_fn that I can use?

(I've looked at tf.cond, and it's not obvious how I can use that in this context.  As I understand it, tf.cond produces an op, not a callable, so how am I going to use that from within a lambda being applied by map_fn?)

Comment: I've just realised that your condition is `x % 2 >= 0`... Isn't that, basically, true for any value of `x`?

Comment: Ooops!  That was a stupid error on my part, sorry.  I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) and [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) like this:

```
elems_shape = tf.shape(elems)
elems_flat = tf.reshape(elems, [-1])
tf_m2_flat = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.cond(x % 2 > 0, lambda: x + 1, lambda: x), elems_flat)
tf_m2 = tf.reshape(tf_m2_flat, elems_shape)
```

But you can also simply use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) like this:

```
tf_m2 = tf.where(elems % 2 > 0, elems + 1, elems)
```

Comment: That works, thanks much!  At least for me, the second and third options need to be callable, so I had to do this: `tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.cond(x % 2 > 0, lambda: x+1, lambda: x), tf_elems)`.  This doesn't work on the column-vector, it complains that the shape is (1,) instead of ().  However, if I flatten it, apply the map_fn, and then reshape it back, it works.  Do I need to worry about the performance overhead of doing that?

Comment: @DavidBolding Sorry, the answer was not very well worked, I forgot about the `lambda:` thing and I didn't took into account that `elems` was two-dimensional, thanks for pointing out the errors. I didn't benchmark it myself, but in principle flattening and reshaping should have virtually no computational cost. I have also added a simpler solution with `tf.where`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tf.where example, I think that'll take care of everything I need in one compact expression.

Comment: How on earth are users supposed to realize that? If you accept a lambda, well... you accept a lambda!! too bad for tensorflow.